# Do I need to have a proxy server to have HTTP over SSH?

Tags: ssh, proxy, http, tunnel, squid

I want to use HTTP over SSH since in my university most of the sites are blocked. I have my own server to which I can using SSH. What I'm doing right now is have a squid proxy run on the server on a particular port. Then connect using putty to my server via ssh and create a tunnel from a certain local port (which I will enter as proxy server in Firefox) to the squid server. So in putty the configuration is like this for the tunnel:

```
 source port:8080
 destination:localhost:3128
```

I want to know is there any other way other than running the squid proxy on my server to tunnel the packets? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

well, i would just skip the whole squid part and use

```
% ssh -N -D 9999 user@myserver
```

which creates a SOCKS-proxy on localhost:9999 ...

Comment: If the university somehow filters DNS requests (which I doubt, but I'm not an expert) then one also might want to ensure the DNS requests are proxied too, for otherwise the browser won't know what IP address to ask for the website. In Firefox use `about:config` to set `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns` to `true` then.